# how to detect in which page we are Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to Rails.
In my appliction.html.erb, i am using a render partial: to use a html_css shared file.
This shared file contains buttons that can be used by different pages.
For example, for the pages /posts and /answers a search field with a suubmit button taken from the shared filed is displayed.
I would like to make this button work for both pages. When we are in the /posts page, we search in the posts and when we are in the /answers page, we search in the answers.

So, i need to call the right controller each time. For that, i need a helper or a trick that enables me to know in which page i am (which controller#index did i call?).

Does rails contain a method or a helper enabling this?

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the helper functions: `controller_name` and `action_name`.

If you have a controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def my_action
    # stuff
  end
end
```

In the view, you can do:

```
Controller name: <%= controller_name %> <br/> # => users
Action name: <%= action_name %> <br/> # => my_action
```

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#routing-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Action and controller are in the params already.  I imagine you would rather do stuff with that information rather than just display it with controller_name/action_name

for instance to display a footer only in the about page assuming the controller is called about_controller you could

```
 <% if params[:controller] == about %>
   <%= render partial: 'footer' %>
 <% end %>
```

`params[:action]` will contain the action.